# Gridlayout in Scrollview android

Tags: android, uiscrollview, grid-layout

I would like to implement an app that fill's a gridlayout with a predefined layout. The grid is not scrollable, it shows the whole gridview. I can't make it work on API 19. I've searched everything but no luck. If it's not possible to implement this, what could be an alternative for this? 
My main layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundGrey"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:rowCount="3"
        app:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        app:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <!-- column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <include layout="@layout/taxi_snippet" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <include layout="@layout/taxi_snippet" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <!-- column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <include layout="@layout/taxi_snippet" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <include layout="@layout/taxi_snippet" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <!-- column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <include layout="@layout/taxi_snippet" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <include layout="@layout/taxi_snippet" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <include layout="@layout/taxi_snippet" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


            <include layout="@layout/taxi_snippet" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <include layout="@layout/taxi_snippet" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">
            <include layout="@layout/taxi_snippet" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

my taxi_snippet layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:background="@drawable/yellowborder"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@color/snippetBackgroundYellow">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_driver" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="4">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/buttonYellow"
            android:text="Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/telefon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/telNumber" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/openingHour"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/openingHours" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/availableAtNight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/atNight" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1.5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"
                android:padding="10sp"
                android:background="@color/snippetBackgroundYellow" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="6sp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite"
                android:background="@color/backgorundGrey" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: WHy ScrollView you are using? As per your design there is no use of it... Are you excluding something while posting this code? If not then, Scrollview and Linerlayout both are useless

Comment: I'm getting all the data from a webservice. Maybe there will be 20 of these taxi_snippet objects.

Comment: In that case use recyclerview with gridlayout manager. It will show same UI as what you have added here but it will give you more flexible ways..

Comment: It's working on pre lollipop devices too?

Comment: Yes. Using support library, this is possible since API 11 (or API 7, need to check)